# How would I change the following script to exclude user names longer than six characters long?

Tags: oracle

select count(*)
from fnd_user
where end_date is null
or end date >= sysdate;

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*) from fnd_user where (end_date is null or end date >= sysdate)
and length(username) <= 6;
```

Comment: -1: The AND will be evaluated before the OR, so this is the equivalent of: end_date is null or (end_date >= sysdate and length(username) <= 6);

Comment: Removed "-1" since query was fixed

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*)
from fnd_user
where (end_date is null or end_date >= sysdate)
and length(username) <= 6;
```